# On scientific temperament surrounding Muscadines

Tags: seeds, propagation, grape-vine, resources, muscadines

Why is there an inherent lack of scientific resources surrounding muscadines? I remember hearing Johnny Cash's 'Hurt' a little over some 4 or 5 years ago and immediately took fancy towards those brass coloured "grapes" which after a bit of research were identified to me as scuppernongs/ muscadines. I was intensely enchanted and almost fast forwarding a few years now, I'm still unable to lay my hands on either muscadines or muscadine seeds/ vines /bareroots /cuttings in my part of world.(Although muscadine seed extracts are sold a lot here). Need plausible reasons for the same. Herein, I have a few questions to aid my understanding.

1.) Why do fewer farmers/ growers grow muscadines, why is much of production undocumented? Can you explain the lack of articles around it?

2.) Do US IP/ GI regulations disallow selling of muscadine vines outside of states? I've checked all over India for Muscadine growers/ suppliers. They either make misleading claims of their "grapes" being true muscadines. Ison's nursery has raised standards of muscadine growing, but they as well don't ship outside USA.

3.) What makes muscadine vines so expensive? For someone from India like me with lower purchasing power parity than US counterparts, it makes it impossible and insanely expensive to lay hands even on seeds (like an amount ≈2,000 INR/$24 USD for mere 5 seeds). It makes them so expensive that students in Bio sciences (like me) frown from ever trying to purchase and grow them here. On contrary, even orchids come off at a far lower prices than muscadines/ muscadine seeds. At a price of a few muscadine seeds here, we can technically purchase an entire Tissue culture protocol for orchids.

4.) Do US air cargo regulations disallow flying muscadines/ muscadine vines due to risk of allowing foreign pests into a different geolocation?

5.) Has someone tried growing muscadines from seeds? How reliable was germination? What were the genetic variations in plants grown from seeds? What was Male : Female : Hermaphrodite ration for plants grown from seeds?

6.) How resilient are muscadines to rainy tropics at elevated altitudes?

Alternately, does someone knows someone who could provide muscadine growing resources (articles/ seeds/ vines/ cuttings )for students/ indie learners?

Comment: India restricts the import of agricultural plants and seeds. To import muscadines, you would have to obtain special permits and pay customs duty. This will definitely prevent the muscadine growers in the US from shipping to India and/or make any that you find hideously expensive. See here:  https://www.nriguides.com/indian-customs-list-of-prohibited-items/#indian-customs-list-of-prohibited-items

Comment: @Jurp Thanks a ton for giving out likely the reasons for it. However, although not within my knowledge, aren't traded/ merchant commodities waived off from customs duties?

Comment: You'd have to check with your government, but muscadines would be considered agricultural in the US. I'd guess that small growers could just send the seeds without declaring what they were, but that is the way in which invasive and problem species enter a country.

Comment: @Jurp That does makes sense! Thanks a ton for the info!✨